# How to Save the Checkbox Value Form to MySQL in One Field

Tags: php, mysql

How to Save the Checkbox Value Form to MySQL in One Field, can anyone help me..[image]
Here is my code:

```
function student($param1 = '') {
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1) {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }

    $running_year = $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description;
    if ($param1 == 'create') {
        $data['ekskul_id'] = $this->input->post('ekskul_id');
        $this->db->insert('student', $data);
    }
}
```

this is my display code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="field-2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ekstrakurikuler</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select data-placeholder="Select" name="ekskul_id[]" multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
        <?php
            $ekstra = $this->db->get('ekstrakurikuler')->result_array();
            foreach($ekstra as $row):
        ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['ekskul_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['ekskul_name'];?></option>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saving multiple values in one column is a _terrible_ database design. You should read up on [database normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) instead.

Comment: Terrible?
ok ready, boss  :D
Thank you sir, for the information

Comment: Yes. Terrible. [Here's an answer pointing out a bunch of reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/2453432).

Comment: And this is very helpful and adds to my experience, thank you, sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code to store multiple id in one field:

```
<?php 
$ekskul_id= implode(",",$_POST['ekskul_id']);
?>
```

In your code :

```
if(isset($this->input->post('ekskul_id'))){
 $data['ekskul_id'] = implode(",",$this->input->post('ekskul_id'));
}
```

Comment: @aviboy2006 `isset` will throw an error as `isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error.`. 

So you need to do it like this `if($this->input->post('ekskul_id'))`.

Comment: @DanzMuhammad what is the datatype for the `ekskul_id ` field?

Comment: Try to print the content of the `$data` before insert statement and look for the comma-separated values in `ekskul_id`

Comment: @Vinay Patil I have searched for tutorials, but all of them are checkboxes of input type not option values, my data type is INTEGER and I want to retrieve all of that data in one field in mysql "1,2,3"

Comment: The major problem is the datatype. As you are storing the comma separated string you need to change field data type to varchar or text. Then above code will work.

Comment: @Vinay Patil I tried using insert_batch and succeeded and entered, but the data entered into two fields in mysql.

Comment: I have tried and changed the type to long_text but the result is NULL and not entered

Comment: Use `$this->db->last_query()` to get the last query executed and paste it here.